# How to read this SQL Date&time pattern?

Tags: sql, xml, regex

Pattern goes like this: `'/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/'`

Can somebody explain how can i put date and time in there in a right way?

It didn't accept `2014-05-18T13:52:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pattern for date. It is a pattern for 24 hour time format, so it matches strings like:

```
4:34
16:03
23:45
10:59
```